# Group data by Time interval in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as below

```
order no        orderdate
01              2012-08-01 00:00
02              2012-08-01 00:10
03              2012-08-01 00:15
04              2012-08-01 00:30
05              2012-08-01 10:00
06              2012-08-01 10:35
07              2012-08-01 14:00
08              2012-08-02 20:30
09              2012-08-02 20:35
10              2012-08-02 23:00
```

I want to group this values by time interval ( like 00 -01, 01- 02 ......22- 23, 23-24) (excluding date value)

how do I write the query to group this by time only?

I want to get 24 row (24 intervals) with count of orders

Comment: you can `GROUP BY CASE WHEN condition1 THEN 1 WHEN condition2 THEN 2...`.

Comment: `I want to get 24 row (24 intervals) with count of orders` !!, Could u provide us with desired output in table formatted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, orderdate)`**.

Query:

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, orderdate) AS HOUR,
       COUNT(*)                  AS ORDERS_PER_HOUR
FROM  YourTable
WHERE CAST(orderdate AS DATE) = @someDate
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, orderdate)
```

Note that the query above will give less than 24 results if not every hour is present in `orderdate`.

If you **need** to have all hours represented, then you can use a Recursive *Common Table Expression* (CTE) to first generate all hours (0-23), and then left join your table with the CTE:

```
;WITH hours AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS h
    UNION ALL
    SELECT h + 1 FROM hours WHERE h < 23
)
SELECT hours.h AS HOUR,
       COUNT(YourTable.[order no]) AS ORDERS_PER_HOUR
FROM      hours
LEFT JOIN YourTable ON DATEPART(HOUR, orderdate) = hours.h
WHERE CAST(orderdate AS DATE) = @someDate
GROUP BY hours.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple solution where you case the hour of the day...

```
drop table if exists dbo.tOrders;

create table dbo.tOrders (
    OrderNo varchar(50)
    , OrderDate datetime
);

insert into dbo.tOrders (OrderNo, OrderDate)
values ('01', '2012-08-01 00:00')
    , ('02', '2012-08-01 00:10')
, ('03',              '2012-08-01 00:15')
, ('04',              '2012-08-01 00:30')
, ('05',              '2012-08-01 10:00')
, ('06',              '2012-08-01 10:35')
, ('07',              '2012-08-01 14:00')
, ('08',              '2012-08-02 20:30')
, ('09',              '2012-08-02 20:35')
, ('10',              '2012-08-02 23:00')



select
    case
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 0 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 1 then '00-01'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 1 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 2 then '01-02'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 2 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 3 then '02-03'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 3 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 4 then '03-04'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 4 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 5 then '04-05'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 5 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 6 then '05-06'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 6 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 7 then '06-07'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 7 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 8 then '07-08'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 8 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 9 then '08-09'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 9 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 10 then '09-10'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 10 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 11 then '10-11'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 11 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 12 then '11-12'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 12 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 13 then '12-13'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 13 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 14 then '13-14'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 14 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 15 then '14-15'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 15 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 16 then '15-16'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 16 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 17 then '16-17'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 17 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 18 then '17-18'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 18 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 19 then '18-19'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 19 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 20 then '19-20'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 20 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 21 then '20-21'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 21 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 22 then '21-22'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 22 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 23 then '22-23'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 23 then '23-00'
    end as TimeOfDay
    , count(t.OrderNo) as OrderCount
from dbo.tOrders t
group by
    case
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 0 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 1 then '00-01'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 1 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 2 then '01-02'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 2 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 3 then '02-03'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 3 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 4 then '03-04'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 4 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 5 then '04-05'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 5 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 6 then '05-06'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 6 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 7 then '06-07'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 7 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 8 then '07-08'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 8 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 9 then '08-09'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 9 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 10 then '09-10'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 10 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 11 then '10-11'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 11 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 12 then '11-12'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 12 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 13 then '12-13'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 13 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 14 then '13-14'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 14 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 15 then '14-15'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 15 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 16 then '15-16'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 16 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 17 then '16-17'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 17 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 18 then '17-18'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 18 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 19 then '18-19'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 19 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 20 then '19-20'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 20 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 21 then '20-21'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 21 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 22 then '21-22'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 22 and datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) < 23 then '22-23'
        when datepart(hour, t.OrderDate) >= 23 then '23-00'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this query.  As you can see the main function to use is `DATE_PART(<format>, <date column>)` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql)  which "Returns an integer that represents the specified datepart of the specified date".

Then you can use GROUP BY to COUNT record for each hour.

And finally you can arrange "output format".

```
 SELECT CAST(X AS VARCHAR(2)) +'-'+CAST(X+1 AS VARCHAR(2)) AS HOUR_GROUP, COUNT(*) AS RC
FROM
 (SELECT  DATEPART(hh,ORD_DATE) X FROM ORD)A
 GROUP BY X
 ;
```

or if you prefer:

```
 SELECT CAST(DATEPART(hh,ORD_DATE)  AS VARCHAR(2)) +'-'+CAST(DATEPART(hh,ORD_DATE) +1 AS VARCHAR(2)) AS HOUR_GROUP, COUNT(*) AS RC
 FROM ORD
 GROUP BY  DATEPART(hh,ORD_DATE)
 ;
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO ORD VALUES (1,'2012-01-08 00:00');
INSERT INTO ORD VALUES (2,'2012-01-08 00:10');
INSERT INTO ORD VALUES (3,'2012-01-08 00:15');
INSERT INTO ORD VALUES (4,'2012-01-08 00:30');
INSERT INTO ORD VALUES (9,'2012-01-08 01:30');
INSERT INTO ORD VALUES (5,'2012-01-08 10:00');
INSERT INTO ORD VALUES(7,'2012-01-08 15:00');
INSERT INTO ORD VALUES (8,'2012-02-08 20:30');
```

Output

```
HOUR_GROUP  RC
0-1     4
1-2     1
10-11   1
15-16   1
20-21   1
```

If you desire all the 24 hours-group you can use:

```
 SELECT RIGHT('0'+CAST(Z AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+'-'+RIGHT('0'+CAST(Z+1 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) AS HOUR_GR, COALESCE(RC,0) AS RC
 FROM (
     SELECT -1+ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A1.Y) AS Z 
     FROM (SELECT 1 AS Y UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5) A1
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS Y UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5) A2
    ) B
 LEFT JOIN  (SELECT X, CAST(X  AS VARCHAR(2)) +'-'+CAST(X +1 AS VARCHAR(2)) AS HOUR_GROUP, COUNT(*) AS RC
             FROM (SELECT  DATEPART(hh,ORD_DATE) X FROM ORD) A
             GROUP BY X
            ) C ON B.Z= C.X
 WHERE B.Z<24
```

Output:

```
HOUR_GR RC
00-01   4
01-02   1
02-03   0
03-04   0
04-05   0
05-06   0
06-07   0
07-08   0
08-09   0
09-10   0
10-11   1
11-12   0
12-13   0
13-14   0
14-15   0
15-16   1
16-17   0
17-18   0
18-19   0
19-20   0
20-21   1
21-22   0
22-23   0
23-24   0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the count by hour regardless of the date, i.e. you are trying to find the busiest times of day?  In which case you can use the following:

```
declare @hours table
(
hourpart datetime
)
INSERT INTO @hours VALUES
('00:00:00'),
('01:00:00'),
('02:00:00'),
('03:00:00'),
('04:00:00'),
('05:00:00'),
('06:00:00'),
('07:00:00'),
('08:00:00'),
('09:00:00'),
('10:00:00'),
('11:00:00'),
('12:00:00'),
('13:00:00'),
('14:00:00'),
('15:00:00'),
('16:00:00'),
('17:00:00'),
('18:00:00'),
('19:00:00'),
('20:00:00'),
('21:00:00'),
('22:00:00'),
('23:00:00')

declare @orders table
(
orderNo int,
orderDate datetime)


INSERT INTO @orders VALUES
(01,'2012-08-01 00:00'),
(02,'2012-08-01 00:10'),
(03,'2012-08-01 00:15'),
(04,'2012-08-01 00:30'),
(05,'2012-08-01 10:00'),
(06,'2012-08-01 10:35'),
(07,'2012-08-01 14:00'),
(08,'2012-08-02 20:30'),
(09,'2012-08-02 20:35'),
(10,'2012-08-02 23:00'),
(11,'2012-08-01 20:25')

SELECT convert(varchar(8), h.hourpart, 108), COUNT(*) FROM @orders o 
INNER JOIN @hours h
ON DATEPART(hour, o.orderdate) = DATEPART(hour, h.hourpart)
GROUP BY h.hourpart
ORDER BY h.hourpart
```

Results:

```
00:00:00    4
10:00:00    2
14:00:00    1
20:00:00    3
23:00:00    1
```